# Halacha of putting on talit Katan in the morning

Tags: blessing, netilat-yadayim-washing, tallit-katan

I was just wondering about the halacha of waking up in the morning and putting on tallit katan. When I wake up I wash my hands (negal vasser) then get dressed and put on my tallit katan with a bracha (I do not war the tallit gadol as I am single).  After this I go to the bathroom.  Is this the correct place to say the bracha or should it be said at a later point?

Comment: Saying a bracha is problematic,one can get dressed then wash hands,then go to bathroom wash again with a bracha.

Comment: I was aking in relation to the baracha on tallis katan. Are you talking about netiyat yadayim?